MUI DesktopDatePicker causes scroll to top in iFrame
I'm trying to use DesktopDatePicker from MUI in an iFrame.
When opening (clicking on button) the page parent page scrolls to the top.


  useEffect(() => {
    if (datePicker.current) {
      const blurPreventButton = datePicker.current.parentElement?.children[1].children[0];
      if (blurPreventButton) {
        blurPreventButton.id = 'openDatePickerButton';
        iframeBlurManipulation();
      }
    }
  }, []);


<DesktopDatePicker
  className="capitalize-text"
  value={selectedDate}
  autoFocus={false}
  slots={{
    day: ServerDay,
  }}
  inputRef={datePicker}
  onChange={handleDateChange}
  shouldDisableDate={shouldDisableDate}
  minDate={dayjs(firstValidDate)}
  slotProps={{
    popper: {
      disablePortal: true,
      autoFocus: false,
    },
  }}
  maxDate={dayjs(Object.values(departureDates).pop() || '')}
/>

I tried something like preventing the focus on the element with a helper function, but that leads to another problem which is clicking outside it scrolls back to the focused element.
Did anyone had issue like this and maybe came up with a working solution?
Adding the helper.js function which helps not to jump, but then causes issue to disable the focus.
export default function iframeBlurManipulation() {
  const button = document.querySelector('#openDatePickerButton');
  if (button) {
    button.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
      event.target.focus();
    });
  }
}



I fixed the issue by using the Material UI StaticDatePicker instead of the DesktopDatePicker. Not really a fix, more a workaround.
